# Chuwi Lark Box - Content Security Policy

Tags: content-security-policy

[image]

Can someone please explain what is going on ?

I often use one information site, where I want and how much I want.
But now I am faced with the problem "Content Security Police", on my new miniPC "Chuwi Lark Box".
Only on this miniPC, I can not download the site, that I use freely and without any problems on all other PCs and smartphones.

What's wrong with my miniPC ?
What can be done to solve this problem ?

I haven't tried anything to solve this problem.
I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The site has started applying the response header "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only". This is Content Security Policy in test mode. Even though you see errors saying the browser refused to load something, this only means what the browser would refuse had the header not used the test version. Most likely the site owner is experimenting with the header. The site may not serve this header to everyone. If the policy has reporting configured the browser will send violation reports, and the site owner might want to limit the amount of such reports by applying the header to a subset of visitors.

Comment: Is there any way I can influence this as a user? On the browser side?

Comment: In Chrome on desktop there is a new function to override response headers in dev tools, that is pretty much your only option as it is a security function not meant to be tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of my problem (my carelessness)
MiniPC Chuwi LarkBox does not store time and date.
Every time you turn it on, it continues to work with an incorrect date and time.
Network time synchronization does not occur immediately.
For this reason, there was a problem with the certificate.
The certificate was rejected because its date was from the future.